# regex to allow space and restrict special characters at the beginning of a non empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a RegExp in javascript. The requirement is to allow spaces at the beginning of a string if the string is non-empty. also, I have to restrict some special characters at the beginning of the string.

Currently, I am using this RegExp -

```
 ^(?!^[=+-@]).*



these strings need to be passed from regexp test - 

foo
foo bar
       bar
       123bar
foo@bar.com



these string should fail - 
@foo
        @foo
'           ...spaces'
'' empty-string
```

Please help.

Comment: Try `^(?! *[=+@-]|\s+$).*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?! *[=+@-]| +$).*
```

Or, to match any kind of whitespaces:

```js
^(?!\s*[=+@-]|\s+$).*
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!\s*[=+@-]|\s+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right from the current location, there is

  - `\s*[=+@-]` - zero or more whitespaces and then `=`, `+`, `@`, or `-`
  - `|` - or
  - `\s+$` - one or more whitespaces till end of string
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.